# Import Values in lookup Columns in Sharepoint Online using CSOM powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to import values in lookup columns, i have country parent list and a child list which has lookup column as Region, am trying below code but it does not seem work at all, i think i am wrong with the syntax may be

```
###### Add all functions here##########
foreach($row in $CSVLocation)
{
$item["ABC_x0020_DEF"]=$row.'ABC DEF'

 ##############
#Get the Lookup Item from Parent List
 $LookupItem = $country.GetItems | Where-Object { $row.'Region' -eq $row["Region"]}

if($LookupItem -ne $null)
{
$RegionLookup = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldLookupValue($LookupItem.ID,$row.Region)

#Set the Lookup field value
$item["Region"] = $RegionLookup
}
}
}
 ##############
     $item.Update();
     $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: What error you are getting? or What is the output you are getting ?

Comment: Hi Ranadip, i am not getting any error, but i am not getting any value in $LookupItem, and it is not going inside if condition also. that is why all other columns's value are getting imported except the lookup one

Comment: I am using the http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/import-from-csv-file-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html reference link to accomplish the same, but it doesn't work

Comment: Give a sample file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not using CSOM object but server side object. It is not `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue` but it is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue`.

Create function for finding the right item in items collection.

```
function Get-Item($Items, $ColumnName, $Value)
{
    foreach ($item in $Items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if ($item[$ColumnName] -eq $Value)
        {
            return $item
        }
    }

    return $null
}
```

You are using the method `GetItems()` incorrectly. It should leverage the `CamlQuery` object.

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$LookupItems = $country.GetItems($query)

# Execute query and get items from SharePoint
$spoCtx.Load($LookupItems)
$spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
```

You don't have to create this FieldLookupValue object, just set the lookup item ID.

```
#Get the Lookup Item from Parent List items collection
$LookupItem = Get-Item -Items $LookupItems -ColumnName "Region" -Value $row.'Region'

if($LookupItem -ne $null)
{
    #Set the Lookup field value
    $item["Region"] = $LookupItem.Id
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,tried this and got error

collection has not been initialized.It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.It may need to be explicitly requested.

$query1 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$LookupItems = $list.GetItems($query1)

$LookupItem = $LookupItems | Where-Object { $_["Template_x0020_Regi"].ToString() -eq $row.'Template Region'}

if($LookupItem -ne $null)
{
$RegionLookup = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue($LookupItem.ID,$row.'Template Region')
 $item["Template_x0020_Regi"] = $LookupItem.ID
}

Comment: I modified my answer. You have to call Load and ExecuteQuery methods to get the items.

Comment: Thank you, no errors now but $Lookupitem is null :(

Comment: See the modification. I added Get-Item function which will find the item in items collection. It seems that Where-Object is not working as expected. Now it should be ok :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you so much, got this error now
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Items'. :( :/

Comment: Did you copy the Get-Item function to your script, right? Where do you get this error? On this line: ``$LookupItem = Get-Item -Items $LookupItems -ColumnName "Region" -Value $row.'Region'``?

Comment: yes getting on this line, as soon i execute this line it throws exceptio